# Setting canonical tags for categories in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6, canonical-link

Is this possible, or is there some code that can be added so I can set a different canonical URL for categories in Magento? I can set for products fine.

Comment: See my answer below. This is now supported out of the box in 1.7.0.2

Comment: Canonical tags has been supported in Magento since 1.4.0.0 RC1 for both product pages and category pages. You will have to add them to the layout on CMS pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box there is nothing for this that I am aware of. You will need to develop or build your own method of doing this.

You will need to create an entry in a layout.xml file to put an additional template in the head section of the page when you are on a category page (this would likely be in a catalog_Category_view block). You would also probably need a view file as well as a Block object to fetch the URL you want to use (technically you could put that in the view file, but having the block object is more "Magento").

Your layout.xml block would look something like this

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="canonical/canonical" name="head_url" as="head_url" template="ocaff/canonical/head.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

This block references a head.phtml file. That file would contain:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $this->getCanonicalUrl() ?>" />
```

This calls back to a block object that has a function called getCanonicalUrl(). In this function you will find and determine what you want the canonical to be. Most likely you want this to be the URL key, but you may have other logic in mind there.

Answer (score 11):

Just found this question while searching for info about canonical URL support.

I'm not sure which version added this (couldn't find anything in release notes), but it is now supported out of the box in 1.7.0.2.

In admin: SYSTEM >> CONFIG >> CATALOG >> SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION

Last two options enable canonical URLs for categories and products.

Comment: Support for Canonical tags was introduced in 1.4.0.0 RC1

Answer (score 0):

Canonical urls for product and category pages are supported by Magento from 1.5

In admin: SYSTEM >> CONFIG >> CATALOG >> SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION